# How to obtain this effect using Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, grayscale

I need a really simple, fool-proof method to obtain this effect: I want to leave the letterbox colored while make all the surrounding area in a deep dim gray shade, the grade of gray that I see is like the one in the other picture.

[image]
[image]

Please consider that I'm pretty new in Photoshop and graphic design in general. I tried using paths to delimit the zone but the result was terrible and not sharp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start by selecting the Polygonal Lasso Tool and then outlining the mailbox. Ideally, you would use the Pen Tool for more precise results, but you wanted simple/quick

[image]

Then, create a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer.  Select it from the options, by clicking this icon at the bottom of your Layers Palette:

[image]

You will now need to invert your Layer Mask.  Do so, by clicking on it, in your Layers Palette to bring up this menu:

[image]

After it's inverted, click just to the left of that little chain link icon, to bring up the options for your Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer and bring the saturation all the way down

[image]

As you may see in the image above, I also decided to decrease the contrast a bit, to make the grays more uniform

Create a Brightness/Contrast Adjustment Layer the same way you made the previous one.  You can then drag your mask from the first layer to your second, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to copy it.  Adjust the parameters to your liking

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll try this, is there a way to make the lasso snap on edges? Like can PS detect there is a border and help me trace it with the lasso?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net you can use the Magnetic Lasso tool, if that's what you want